Postfix responds locally but not remotely - no it is not the firewall
I've got Postfix setup on a new Ubuntu 24.04 server.  If I telnet to it locally it responds with the SMTP banner as expected.  If I telnet to it from an external source though it opens the port and then does nothing i.e. I get a blank screen and a "452 syntax error(connecting)" error for any command I send (helo, ehlo, helo mail.test.com, etc.).  Obviously it is not a firewall issue as postfix answers, it just seems to not want to service requests from the external network.
I have checked and double checked all of the configuartion, restarted services and even restarted the machine.  I'm at a loss as to what may be causing this issue.
/etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 3.6

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/nginx/ssl/************/2275563/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/nginx/ssl/************/2275563/server.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ************
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = virtuallyanything.com, $myhostname, svr-virtuallyanything.localdomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = smtp.postmarkapp.com:2525 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/pgsql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/pgsql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/pgsql_virtual_alias_dom>
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/pgsql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/pgsql_virtual_alias>
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
milter_protocol = 6
milter_mail_macros = i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen}
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:11332
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:11332

/etc/postfix/master.cf
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -v
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
#127.0.0.1:submission inet n -   y       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=static:all
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#     Instead of specifying complex smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions here,
#     specify "smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions=$mua_<xxx>_restrictions"
#     here, and specify mua_<xxx>_restrictions in main.cf (where
#     "<xxx>" is "client", "helo", "sender", "relay", or "recipient").
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
# Choose one: enable submissions for loopback clients only, or for any client.
#127.0.0.1:submissions inet n  -       y       -       -       smtpd
#submissions     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submissions
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=static:all
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#     Instead of specifying complex smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions here,
#     specify "smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions=$mua_<xxx>_restrictions"
#     here, and specify mua_<xxx>_restrictions in main.cf (where
#     "<xxx>" is "client", "helo", "sender", "relay", or "recipient").
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRXhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRX user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
#scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FRX user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}


Are you sure that when you externally connect to port 25 of your (postfix) server that the connection really reaches your server? Some ISPs or cloud providers may filter TCP port 25 or route to somewhere else. You should test the TCP port 25 connection is really established by using tcpdump on your server.

Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show system logs that cover the event.  Each log message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in [] of the issuer and a colon (:). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read man logger, for a clearer explanation.

"for any command I send" - please edit your question to quote the actual commands you tried. Did you try EHLO? With which argument?

@FedKad Thanks, you got it in one.  I don't understand what was actually allowing the port to be opened in the first place though.  I guess the provider's device was answering the port call and just not forwarding it to the server.  If you want to change your comment to an answer so I can give you the credit for answering it.  The annoying part is the hosts documentation says they only block port 25 on outgoing connections and makes no mention of blocking incoming port 25 as well.

If it is not a privacy issue for you, please specify your Internet or virtual server provider.

Despite my initial belief it was a firewall issue.  As per FedKad's comment the VPS provider was sending the connection to a dead end even though their documentation only said they were blocking outgoing port 25, not incoming.
